# AWS IoT-Cloud QoS-2: Is the message assured delivery when the receiver is a AWS Lambda or any other service in the Cloud?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have some devices connected in the AWS IoT-Core MQTT broker that I want to use the QoS 2 flag.

It seems that the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html) probably is not updated yet. Here we see that QoS 2 is not available yet.

AWS IoT and the AWS IoT Device SDKs support the MQTT Quality of Service (QoS) levels 0 and 1. **The MQTT protocol defines a third level of QoS, level 2, but AWS IoT does not support it**. Only the MQTT protocol supports the QoS feature. HTTPS supports QoS by passing a query string parameter ?qos=qos where the value can be 0 or 1.

By the most recent (3 weekes ago) IoT AWS training, we can see that the QoS 2 messages is assured delivery:

[image]

My question is if the message is assured delivery and the receptor is a Lambda or any other service in the cloud, and let's say that for some moment the service is out, do qe have a guarantee that the message will be consumed when the lambda or the service is available?

Comment: Here is what I think. first hopefully AWS is supporting QoS2, I need that for my project. I guess message broker should be the receptor, because delivery of message is between broker and the device. If broker receive the message but lambda is not available probably message will get lost, I will put a Message Queue in between just in case. I hope my assumption is correct :)

Comment: Now there is an option in AWS IoT core that mantain the message until be consumed.

Comment: Also I learned that AWS does not support QoS2. And actually it is not needed for most of the time level 1 is what mostly enough. Duplicate message need to be handled.